# C++ I'm having trouble setting up a priority queue of a class I created

Tags: c++, vector, priority-queue

I'm trying to set up a priority queue of a class I created called Event.  In the 2 lines before I try this, I have 2 other priority queues set up that seem to work fine but I get an error on the 3rd one.  Any suggestions?

```
class Event{
    enum eventType { Arrival, CPUburstCompletion, IOcompletion, TimerExpired };
    double time; // Defined as time units since the start of the simulation
};

vector<process> processTable;
int CPU;
int IO;
priority_queue< int, vector<int> > readyQueue;
priority_queue< int, vector<int> > IO_Queue;
priority_queue< Event, vector<Event> > eventQueue;
```

I did not have a comparator function in my Event class.  I put this in yet I'm still getting an error.  Did I not write the comparator correctly?

```
class Event{
    enum eventType { Arrival, CPUburstCompletion, IOcompletion, TimerExpired };
    double time; // Defined as time units since the start of the simulation
    bool operator()(Event& e1, Event& e2){
        if (e1.time < e2.time){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
};

vector<process> processTable;
int CPU;
int IO;
priority_queue< int, vector<int> > readyQueue;
priority_queue< int, vector<int> > IO_Queue;
priority_queue< Event, vector<Event> > eventQueue;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a comparison operator, either in the Event class, or as a template parameter to the priority queue.

```
class Event{
 ...
  public: 
     bool operator<(const Event &other) const {return time < other.time;}
};
```

Comment: Note: This basically almost never makes sense. 97.2% of the time you should make a custom comparator, not do this.

Comment: @How so, @Dave? This seems to make perfect sense and obeys the rules of encapsulation - whether one object is less than another is a property of the class, not some external function, surely? Or is this part of the other 2.8%? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo `1 second < 2 seconds`... that makes sense. `event1 < event2` could mean anything... there's nothing about an `Event` that implies what less than could mean for it. And except for bizarre cases if you define an `operator<` it almost always makes sense to do the other 5 comparison operators. In cases like this, where you only make an `operator<` to satisfy sorting in containers, it's much clearer and more correct to tell the container "sort my `Event`s based on their time"...(by using a custom comparator)

Comment: @Dave, if an event is a point in time, it makes perfect sense. No so much for a duration since it's not so obvious _which_ time point should be used but I don't think that's the case here, the event types are clearly point-in-time objects. Even for durations, I'd probably (as a personal preference) use encapsulated comparisons and just document what they mean, but I can see where you're coming from.

Comment: @paxdiablo I didn't pay attention here, I didn't realize this was _that_ kind of event (I was thinking the message kind and didn't bother reading). So ya I think it makes sense for this case. Although I would still define the other 5 operators too.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not specify a `Compare` template argument, you have to declare an `operator<` in your Event struct. How else is the queue to know which is the minimum element to extract?